# Some system notifications are not registering under AccesibilityService

Tags: android, wifi, accessibilityservice

Like many others I want my app to detect notifications as my app needs to hide for each notification.

Most status bar notifications arrives fine. 
But 2 of the system notifications won't register :

- The Wifi available that's showing each time the device detects open wireless network.
- The Connected as media storage for MTP.

I'm running with 4.2.2 on nexus devices.

My accessibilityserviceinfo is as follow :

```
<?xmlversion="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
    <accessibility-service xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:accessibilityEventTypes="typeNotificationStateChanged" 
        android:accessibilityFeedbackType="feedbackAllMask"
        android:accessibilityFlags="flagIncludeNotImportantViews"
        />
```

Thank you.

Comment: still wondering about this. however looking at AOSP it seems like the Android Notifications manager simply not calling AccessibiltyService for intents that are being canceled. so in the case of MTP or Wifi once called they're canceling it. this also seems to show in the LogCat as notification without icon being ignored.

Comment: Update as of December 2013, Since 4.3 the issues seems to be fixed. both for Accessibility and NotificationListener.